# Defining a tsconfig for CLI tools within a svelte-kit package

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, sveltekit

I've written a svelte-kit app that hits a backend database.

I've also written CLI tools needed to maintain the database alongside the app.

I want to keep the app and the CLI tools in the same repo, because they share code, but the `"type":"module"` that svelte-kit requires in `package.json` prevents me from compiling the CLI tools using the svelte-kit tsconfig.

So I set out to create a `tsconfig.tools.json` for building the CLI tools. But I have not yet succeeded in crafting one that works despite having `"type":"module"` in package.json

Here's my latest attempt:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "target": "es2020",
        "lib": ["es2020"],
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "strict": true,
        "pretty": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "outDir": "build"
    },
    "include": [
        "src/tools/**/*.ts",
        "src/model/**/*.ts",
        "src/shared/**/*.ts",
        "src/integrations/**/*.ts",
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules/**",
        "./**/*.test.ts"
    ]
}
```

This attempt yields the following error on compilation:

```
ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and
'/Users/joe/repos/cavesite/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a
CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
```

TypeScript has been very creative with the reasons it gives for not building my CLI tool, depending on what I put in `tsconfig.tools.json`. The above is just the latest reason.

Any suggestions on how I accomplish this? I'd hate to have to factor out the common code into a separate repo.

Comment: I'm going to just post a quick comment as I'm pretty rushed and slammed with work right now. But the error output is telling you what is wrong...or at least it seems to be trying to direct you towards the issue. It is pointing out the `.cjs` file format isn't being. used correctly. For example I know that if you add `"type":"module"` to your package.json file then you are suppose to convert your `.eslintrc.js` file to be `.eslintrc.cjs` file. My guess is something similar is happening for you.

Comment: @BryceHayden, that was the first thing I tried, but SvelteKit does not build with that change.